# Generate multiple rows from row with bitmask

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets have table with 3 columns: key, value, and bitmask (as varchar; of unknown maximum length):

```
abc | 23 | 101
xyz | 56 | 000101
```

Is it possible to write query, where on the output I will get one row for every combination of key, value, and `1` in bitmask, with index of that `1` as integer column (doesnt matter if starting from 0 or 1)? So for example above:

```
abc | 23 | 1
abc | 23 | 3
xyz | 56 | 4
xyz | 56 | 6
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better off choosing a maximum length for your varchar.

```
SELECT * FROM
table 
INNER JOIN
generate_series(1,1000) s(n) 
ON 
  s.n <= char_length(bitmask) and 
  substring(bitmask from s.n for 1) = '1'
```

We generate a list of numbers:

```
s.n
---
1
2
3
4
...
```

And join it to the table in a way that causes repeated table rows:

```
s.n bitmask
--- ------- 
1   000101
2   000101
3   000101
4   000101
5   000101
6   000101
1   101
2   101
3   101
```

Then use the s.n to substring the bitmask, and look for being equal to 1:

```
s.n bitmask substr
--- ------- ------
1   000101  --substring('000101' from 1 for 1) = '1'? no
2   000101  --substring('000101' from 2 for 1) = '1'? no
3   000101  --substring('000101' from 3 for 1) = '1'? no
4   000101  --substring('000101' from 4 for 1) = '1'? yes...
5   000101
6   000101
1   101
2   101
3   101
```

So the s.n gives us the number in the last column of your desired output, and the where filters to only rows where the string substring works out

Comment: Well, this is what I call thinking out of the box - joining series of numbers and filter that by regex. Hats off to you, sir, and thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, i should have explained a bit about how it works!